# no test for session key if sent by application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I'm writing a non browser application using rails as server.
As I understand, I need to add the received session key to any successive request.

If logged through a browser, it is indeed checked as deleting the cookie during a sesion will fail session test for any request senf afterwards.

However, in my application, I can send any request after logging in, not including the session cookie and it will pass the session test and execute.

I can point out I disabled protect_from_forgery but this should apply only to authenticity_token check, shouldn't it ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: We'll likely need some code snippets related to your "session test" and how you're handling the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a non-browser application, there's no real reason to use cookies (or the session for that matter).  Just authenticate using [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) by sending the credentials on every request as part of the HTTP header.  The basic authentication credentials can be something traditional like a username and password, or something more suited for your needs like an api_key or token.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for you answer.
I would like to stick, if possible, to the standard session managment as I would like to use the same server code for both brosers and applications, also, I will next want to do some SSL encription for the login request, and would like to avoid that for every subsequent requests. If you have further insight, it could do much help.